# Is it possible to achieve sub-meter accuracies with a smartphone, without using an external GNSS-receiver?

Tags: gps, software-recommendations, android, accuracy, dgps

I am currently working with QField on my tablet (Samsung Galaxy Tab S5e) and my smartphone (Samsung Galaxy A40). Since the positioning accuracy on my devices is rather low (absolute best case ~3m on an open field with clear sky), I am looking for lowcost ways to improve it in real time. Due to the high costs, I don't want to use an external GNSS receiver.

I've read that with RTK networks accuracies can be improved to sub-meter levels if you have raw measurements from your GNSS receiver, use a Ntrip-client and have access to correction data.
This discussion: [GNSS raw measurements on Android: Does real time/post processing Differential techniques possible?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/285000/gnss-raw-measurements-on-android-does-real-time-post-processing-differential-te), and this article and the corresponding video: https://www.gpsworld.com/how-to-achieve-1-meter-accuracy-in-android/; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vywGgSrGODU
gave me an overview of the topic, but I am still missing some things:

In the mentioned article/video from 2018 it says that there might be apps in a few years which will offer high-accuracy positioning with your smartphone. Does anyone know of an app that has been developed in the meantime and that achieves sub-meter accuracies with the GNSS-data received from a smartphone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This thread on the GPSTest Google Group discusses this topic:
https://groups.google.com/g/gpstest_android/c/uT2fmvu7ktA

That thread lists several apps, although I don't know if any of them have definitively proven sub-meter accuracy:

> - PPP WizLite : by the French Agency, app pulled from Play Store for unknown reasons but still available on repo sites like APKPure
> - Project Possum : https://gmvnsl.com/about-nsl/nsl-blog/15-products-and-services/66-possum -  using data from SBAS DFMC (satellite-based augmentation system dual-frequency multi-constellation)
> - Project Flamingo : https://www.flamingognss.com/ by far the most advanced project with all the details available in "The FLAMINGO Final Public Report" dated  20/08/2020 - no public app made available and no recent news, might be dead
>   ...
> - 3PGo: https://spaceopal.com/navcast/navcast-app/. These guys are also making the Galileo reference HAS user algorithm.

I've been tracking open-source GNSS apps here:

https://github.com/barbeau/awesome-gnss#android-apps-open-source

...but I don't know of any that have proven sub-meter accuracy using integrated GPS.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way to get horizontal accuracy down to 2cm use an affordable gnss reciever with RTK correction like the ublox F9P (see https://www.ardusimple.com/ or https://www.sparkfun.com/).

Comment: 2cm is really unlikely without an expensive (survey or higher-grade Mapping / GIS antenna).  10cm to 30cm, maybe.  Better than that, not easily?